# recursion - adding numbers from two lists to an new list

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, parameters

Stackoverflow.

I have two ArrayLists, one which contains the numbers 1,2,3,4,5(list1) and another list that contains 6,7,8,9,10,11,12 (list2).

I'm writing a recursing program that adds all of these numbers into a new list(list3). It has to add the first number from list1, then the first number from list2, then the 2nd number from list1, and then the 2nd number from list2 and so on.

If one of the lists contains more numbers than the other, then it should simply add the remaining numbers to the back of the list. In this case, the numbers 11 and 12 should be added.

The output I get now is:  [1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10] but it should be:  [1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4, 9, 5, 10, 11, 12]

The error is "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5" but I don't know how to work around that.
It says there's in error at the two lines where I'm adding to list3.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;


 public class Ex12_2_alternate {
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    //adds 1 - 5 (both incl.) to list1
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        list1.add(i);
    }

    // adds 6 - 12 (both incl.) to list2
    for (int i = 6; i <= 12; i++) {
        list2.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println("list1: " + list1);
    System.out.println("list2: " + list2);

    alternate(list1,list2);

}

private static void alternate(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {

    List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int j = 0;
    int k = list1.size() + list2.size();
    while (j < k) {
        list3.add(list1.get(j));
        list3.add(list2.get(j));
        System.out.println("list3 so far: " + list3);
        j++;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: There is no recursion in that code.

Comment: When J = 6 what will `list3.add(list1.get(j));` do?

Comment: This program is not recursive, it is iterative. Also, k will always be greater than both the sizes of list1 and list2 (because you're adding their sizes together), so you will always go out of bounds.  You need to determine which list is smaller and loop on that size. Then loop through the remaining elements of the larger list.

Comment: @molbdnilo, oh... I thought it had a little recursion. How far off am I?

Comment: @chancea, IndexOutOfBounds: Index: 6, Size: 5 <-- that's the error I get when I change J to 6. I've tried 5 but then I still get the error.

Comment: @AdemÖkmen Exactly, do you understand why you are getting that error?

Comment: @AdemÖkmen For it to be recursive, `alternate` should call `alternate` and not use a loop of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution you can implement is only running your `while` loop while your count is *smaller* than the size of your smaller list.  After that existing `while` loop you have, you can simply iterate adding the remaining elements from your larger list to `list3`. 
 It is a good exercise for you to try writing this yourself. Note that your current error is a result of your method looking for an element at index 6 in `list1`, but evidently there is no value at that index.

Answer (score 0):

`public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("init");
        List list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        List list2 = new ArrayList<>();

```
    //adds 1 - 5 (both incl.) to list1
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        list1.add(i);
    }

    // adds 6 - 12 (both incl.) to list2
    for (int i = 6; i <= 12; i++) {
        list2.add(i);
    }

    List<Integer> list3=recursive(list1, list2, new ArrayList<Integer>());

    Iterator<Integer> it=list3.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.print(it.next() +" ");
    }

}

private static List<Integer> recursive(List<Integer>list1, List<Integer> list2,List<Integer> list3)
{
    if(list1.isEmpty()&&list2.isEmpty())
    {
        return list3;
    }
    if(!list1.isEmpty())
    {
     list3.add(list1.remove(0));
    }
    if(!list2.isEmpty())
    {
     list3.add(list2.remove(0));
    }
     return recursive(list1, list2,list3);
}`
```